# Adding a model attribute from json post method

Tags: java, jquery, json, spring, spring-mvc

I am using `Spring MVC`.

I have a `$.ajax` POST request to do some calculation and in return I get a Json object back.

While I am doing this, can I add another model attribute using `model.addattribute(x,y)`from this method.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/loadPOAction", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody OrderSearch loadOrder(HttpServletRequest request, Model model,@RequestBody final  OrderSearch search) {

   System.out.println(search.getVal());

  model.addAttribute("name", "to be added to model");
  return search;
}
```

Is it feasible? I tried but couldn't get the value of `${name}` in the `JSP`.

Comment: Your code doesn't make a whole lot sense to me. Per your method signature it returns a `JsonOrder` object. The `model` object you are adding your attribute to is not used for anything else (should it be returned?). Then you return `search` which is of type `OrderSearch`. Can you clean up your code or provide more details on what exactly you want to return?

Comment: @JWK Sorry ..my bad .. I was cleaning up to make the code readable. I have modified the return type as the OrderSearch. The basic idea that I am looking here for is if it is possible to add the model.addattribute through this method.. and how to use that in JSP.

Comment: The return type of `OrderSearch` still doesn't make sense to me. Not if you want to render a JSP. See my answer regarding how to render the JSP. If you return an object like `OrderSearch` that would most likely result in a JSON return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to add any attributes to the JSP that you rendered previously. That JSP has been processed and returned to the client, and is thus out of the reach of the server-side context.

As far as reusing data/objects across multiple requests, you would typically implement a caching strategy. This is kind of out of the scope of your question and I suggest reading up on it here: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#cache

**If you want to return a JSON object that contains additional attributes**, then you need to

- either add values directly to the `search` object (if it has the necessary fields)
- or copy the desired fields into a new object (could be a Map or a concrete class)

then return that object (adjusting your method signature accordingly).

For example:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/loadPOAction", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody OrderSearch loadOrder(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestBody OrderSearch search) {

  // set on search object if possible
  search.setName("my name which I retrieved from somewhere");

  // alternatively, you could create a map with the values you need and return it
  // (requires you to change the method return type to Map
  Map<String, Object> resultMap = new HashMap<>();
  resultMap.put("name", "my name");
  resultMap.put("incomingSearch", search);
  resultMap.put("someSearchValue", search.getSomeValue());

  // alternatively, create a new "OrderSearchResponse" class and return an instance of it
  OrderSearchResponse searchResponse = new OrderSearchResponse();
  searchReponse.setName("my name");
  searchResponse.setSomeValue("some value");

  return search; // or resultMap or searchReponse depending on what you do above
}
```

**If you wanted to render another JSP**, you would change your method to the following (note the return type of `String`):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/loadPOAction", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String loadOrder(HttpServletRequest request, Model model, @RequestBody final  OrderSearch search) {

  model.addAttribute("search", search);
  model.addAttribute("name", "to be added to model");

  return "theNameOfYourJspView";
}
```

Then, in your `theNameOfYourJspView` you can use `${search.someValue}` as well as `${name}`.

Comment: Actually the problem is that the page has already been rendered and a button is clicked which passes a Json object OrderSearch. It fetches necessary data from database and gets enriched/ populated with values and hence returned. $.ajax needs a Json object in return on the same page. Returning the nameofJSP wouldnt help.

Comment: Ok, so then you are not using JSP for the return object... I updated my answer with some options you have. Basically, you will just have to return an object. If you can enrich the `OrderSearch` object, then that would probably be easiest. Otherwise, you will need to get the data into some other object which you then return.

Comment: Yeah .. I have something like the resultMap which I want to use in the JSP. But is there a way to maintain a global copy of the resultMap in JSP just like modelAttributes ? .. as in .. if I want to use it in Select box or some other javascript code .. how can it be readily available

Comment: You keep mentioning JSP but I just don't see where you use it. Also not sure what you mean with "global copy". If you want to use the same data in multiple places, you should probably just cache it.

Comment: My main idea of this question is to find out if model.addAttribute will be available on the JSp ?

Comment: If you mean the one that was previously rendered? No.

Comment: Okay .. as you mentioned about caching .. how do we cache the fetched json data and how do we use it .. can u please give a small snippet of the same.. that would be very helpful..Thanks in advance !!

Comment: We are moving away from your original question. I think as far as your original question I answered it. Please accept my answer and create a new question regarding the caching. I suggest you read the relevant section in the documentation first though: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#cache